# How to get the reason (error) of TC failure on fly using Ruby + Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I am trying to do some specific logic in "after (:each)" declarations for failed TCs.
How to catch the fact and the reason of TC failure using Ruby and Rspec methods?
I tried something like:

```
  after(:each) do
    if RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
      e = RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
      puts "Error is: " + e.to_s
      @driver.save_screenshot "../Reports/#{e}.png"
    end
  end
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.after(:each) do |result|
        if result.exception
          res = result.metadata[:example_group][:full_description].to_s + result.metadata[:description].to_s
          @driver.save_screenshot "../Reports/#{res}.png"
        end
      end
end
```